# Install Ubuntu 13.04 on Sony Vaio E Series SVE14125CNB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, vaio, sony

Please help me to install Ubuntu 13.04 in a dual boot setup with Windows 8 on my Sony Vaio E Series SVE14125CNB laptop. When I try to install Ubuntu, after the installation is finished, the system gives me a message that says: operating system missing. Then I changed the BIOS setting as normal, and it only boots Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I also have SVE14125CNB laptop and I installed Ubutnu 13.04 (dual boot with Windows 8) by following instructions given in this link [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported)

How did you install Ubuntu in first place and what BIOS settings did you change? May be you will have to fix grub. Read about it here [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)